# Generating dates with an interval of one year with month and day being constant in python

Tags: python

I have a few dates stored in a list U, I want to generate a sequence of dates for every individual date from years 1981 to 2018 with month and day being constant. I have used relativedelta() command from dateutil library.

```py
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    import datetime
    
    U=[datetime.date(2013,6,5),datetime.date(2014,7,8),datetime.date(2012,12,5)]
    U[0]+relativedelta(years=1)
```

But `relativedelta(years=1)` will fetch only `datetime.date(2014,6,5)`, how to generate dates as `datetime.date(1981,Month,Day)`, `datetime.date(1982,Month,Day)` so on till `datetime.date(2018,Month,Day)` for all the three different dates in U

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it simple by using a list comprehension. If lets say, you want all First of Januaries between 1980 & 2019:

```
[datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) for year in range(1980,2020)]
```

(If want October 30, change `1`, `1` to `10`, `30`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Zabop for the solution. I wanted to generate the sequence for all the three dates, here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

U=[datetime.date(2013,6,5),datetime.date(2014,7,8),datetime.date(2012,12,5)]
x=list()
for i in np.arange(0,3,1):
           X1=[datetime.datetime(year, U[i].month, U[i].day) for year in range(1980,2020)]
           x.append(X1)
```